# ReactJS multiple useState hooks not updating state in Promise resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a function that fires onClick and is supposed to save an array of states to Firebase. There are two states that can fail due to async, so I tried to chain it all in Promises. The Promises are definitely resolving correctly, but the useState hook didn't update the state in resolve when I tried it. So I tried to chain it in the manner below and the same error (Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path.) is still returning. Why would my states for mid and lastUpdated be empty?

```js
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

const initialFieldValues = {
  mid: "",
  lastUpdated: "",
};

const [store, setStore] = useState(initialFieldValues);

const createMID = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let docID = db.collection("merchant").doc().id;
    let key = "mid-".concat(docID);
    if (key) {
      resolve(key);
    } else {
      reject("failed to create mid key");
    }
  });
};

const getTimestamp = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    if (timestamp) {
      resolve(timestamp);
    } else {
      reject("failed to get timestamp");
    }
  });
};
    const registerMerchant = () => {
        createMID()
        .then(
            (data) => {
            setStore({
                ...store,
                mid: data,
            });
            console.log(data); //correctly returns data
            console.log(store.mid); //returns empty; setStore isn't setting the state

            return getTimestamp();
        }).then(
            (data2) => {
            setStore({
                ...store,
                lastUpdated: data2,
            })
            console.log(data2); //returns object
            console.log(store.mid); //returns empty
            }
        ).then(
            () => {
                if(!merchant && authenticated){
                    dispatch({
                        type: "SET_MERCHANT",
                        merchant: store,
                      });
                } else if(merchant) {
                    return
                }else{
                      dispatch({
                        type: "SET_MERCHANT",
                        merchant: null,
                      });
                }
            }
        ).then( ()=> {
            // e.preventDefault();
            
            db.collection('merchant').doc(store.mid).set(store);
        }).catch(error => alert(error.message))
    }
```

Comment: You have some syntax errors. Please may you fix them?

Comment: I think I fixed it.

Comment: I can see that `resolve(key` doesn't have a closing `)` this may cause issues.

Comment: It does. Closing parentheses is on the line below?

Comment: Your promise-chain is not correct: in `registerMerchant`, second `then()` method call should be passed a callback function that _returns_ the result of calling `getTimestamp`. You could also return the result of calling `getTimestamp` from the callback function of the first `then` method and get rid of the second `then` method.

Comment: Good point. I found the formatting a little difficult to follow

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I'm relatively new to the JS in general. I changed second then to .then(()=>{return getTimestamp()}) and the error is still the same. I thought the return statement in getTimestamp function get it to return?

Comment: @Yousaf I tried what you suggested and I've updated `registerMerchant` and added some comments on what I see in the console logs. The same error is still returning, and as far as I can tell, the setStore hook isn't being called? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: state is updated asynchronously and the component can't see the updated state until it re-renders. Logging the state right after calling the state setter function will log the old state, instead of the updated state.